# Insert a line of text in the end of a function

Tags: shell, unix, sed

How would I go about inserting a line of text in the end of a specific function which is present in multiple files in a code tree.
sample example below 
file1 - location - /home/tmp/a/a.sh

```
hello()
{
   echo "line 1"
   echo "line 2"
   insert new line of text "good bye" here
}
```

file2 - location - /home/tmp/b/b.sh

```
hello()
{
   echo "line 1"
   echo "line 2"
   echo "line 3"
   echo "line 4"
   insert new line of text "good bye" here
}
```

I was trying with sed command , but this above scenario looks little tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/^hello()/,/^}/s/^}/   insert new line of text "good bye" here\n&/' file
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

Comment: Nicely done; the only thing needed to make this work with BSD/macOS Sed is to replace the final `\n` with `\ ` followed by an _actual_ newline, or, in Bash, to replace it with `'$'\\\n''`.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Only thing \n did not work..I am able to insert a line as mentioned by @mklement0

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea would be to look for the function specification line up to the end-of-function line, and in that range, insert the extra text before the end-of-function line:

**`it59.sed`**

```
/^hello()/,/^}/ { /^}/i\
    insert new line of text "goodbye" here
}
```

**Usage**

```
sed -f it59.sed file1.sh file2.sh
```

Or, doing in situ editing with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i -f it59.sed file1.sh file2.sh
```

Or, doing in situ editing with BSD `sed`:

```
sed -i '' -f it59.sed file1.sh file2.sh
```

Etc.

**Example input**

```
hello()
{
   echo "line 1"
   echo "line 2"
   #insert new line of text "good bye" here
}

hello()
{
   echo "line 1"
   echo "line 2"
   echo "line 3"
   echo "line 4"
   #insert new line of text "good bye" here
}
```

**Example output**

```
hello()
{
   echo "line 1"
   echo "line 2"
   #insert new line of text "good bye" here
insert new line of text "goodbye" here
}

hello()
{
   echo "line 1"
   echo "line 2"
   echo "line 3"
   echo "line 4"
   #insert new line of text "good bye" here
insert new line of text "goodbye" here
}
```

Note that the leading blanks were ignored by `sed`.  That's a nuisance.  Fixing that is a bit harder.

**`it61.sed`**

```
/^hello()/,/^}/ { /^}/ { h; s/.*/   insert new line of text "goodbye" here/p; x; }; }
```

For the range from the start of the function to the end of the function, if the line matches the end of the function, copy the line to the hold space, replace the line with the new text and print the line, and swap the hold space back.  The semicolon after the `}` is needed by BSD `sed` but not by GNU `sed`.  That single line can also be written out on the command line, of course.  The multiline version (`it59.sed`) requires some care when written on the command line — again, GNU `sed` has different rules from BSD `sed` and allows things that BSD `sed` doesn't.  (POSIX `sed` hews closer to BSD `sed` than GNU `sed` on these issues.)

**Example output**

```
hello()
{
   echo "line 1"
   echo "line 2"
   #insert new line of text "good bye" here
   insert new line of text "goodbye" here
}

hello()
{
   echo "line 1"
   echo "line 2"
   echo "line 3"
   echo "line 4"
   #insert new line of text "good bye" here
   insert new line of text "goodbye" here
}
```